# Finding a closed form $x_n$ for the recurrence relation $x_{n+2} = px_{n+1} + qx_n + r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation:
>   $$
> x_{n+2} = px_{n+1} + qx_n + r
> $$
>   Find the general term $x_n$ given initial conditions $x_1 = a$ and $x_2 = b$, where $a,b,p,q,r$ are some given numbers, $n \in \mathbb N$.

Since this is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation i've started with solving for $x_n^h$ which is a solution for homogeneous relation:

$$
x_{n+2} - px_{n+1} - qx_n = 0 \\
\lambda^2-p\lambda - q = 0
$$

I'm assuming here that two distinct roots $\lambda_{1,2}$ exist for this equation (single root case is handled similarly). So the general term is in the form:

$$
x_n = C_1\lambda_1^{n-1}+C_2\lambda_2^{n-1}
$$

With the initial condition it's possible to find the values for $C_1$ and $C_2$:

$$
C_1 + C_2 = a \\
C_1\lambda_1 + C_2\lambda_2 = b
$$

After solving the system of equation with respect to $C_1$ and $C_2$:

$$
C_1 = \frac{b-a\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \\
C_2 = \frac{b-a\lambda_1}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1} \\
$$

Which eventually results in:

$$
x_n^h = \frac{(a\lambda_2 - b)\lambda_1^{n-1} - (a\lambda_1-b)\lambda_2^{n-1}}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}
$$

Final solution consists of a sum of particular and homogeneous solutions, but that is where I got stuck. What is the way to find the particular solution for the given problem? I'm pretty new to such kind of problems so any details are very much appreciated.

**upd:**

Based on the technique in @rtybase answer here are my findings:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= a \\
x_2 &= b \\
x_3 &= pb - qa + r
\end{align}
$$

Writing the system for $c_1, c_2, c_3$:

$$
\begin{align}
a &= c_1 + c_2 + c_3 \\
b &= c_1\lambda_1 + c_2\lambda_2 + c_3 \\
pb+qa+r &= c_1\lambda_1^2 + c_2\lambda_2^2 + c_3
\end{align}
$$

Now solving for the coefficients gives a huge formula. The answer to this problem suggests that:

$$
x_n = \frac{(\lambda_2(a+\gamma) - b -\gamma)\lambda_1^{n-1} - (\lambda_1(a + \gamma) - (b-\gamma))\lambda_2^{n-1}}{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1} - \gamma
$$

Where:

$$
\gamma = \frac{r}{p+q-1}
$$

Unfortunately I was not able to arrive at exactly the same result, but testing my solution (not posting since it's monstrously big) using `SameQ` in Mathematica with the given answer shows that they are equivalent. Those transformations are not very obvious to me, so i skipped them since the answer matches the given one (yet the symbolic expressions are different)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. From
$$x_{n+2} = px_{n+1} + qx_n + r$$
$$x_{n+3} = px_{n+2} + qx_{n+1} + r$$
we have
$$x_{n+3}-(p+1)x_{n+2}+(p-q)x_{n+1}+qx_{n}=0$$
with characteristic polynomial
$$x^3-(p+1)x^2+(p-q)x+q=0$$
or
$$(x-1)(x^2-px-q)=0 \iff (x-1)(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)=0$$
and finally
$$x_n=C_1\lambda_1^n+C_2\lambda_2^n+C_3$$
which, judging from the question, you know how to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have $x_{n+2} = px_{n+1}+qx_n + r$ where $p,q,r$ are constants and $p+q \geq 2 > 1$ you can try with a constant sequence, $x_n \equiv k$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (ignore my other comment, I haven't read the question carefully)