# Find a closed form of $x_{n+2} = x_{n+1}+2x_n +2$ where $x_1 = x_2 = 1$, $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Find a closed form $x_n$ for the following recurrence relation: 
>   $$
> x_{n+2} = x_{n+1} + 2x_n + 2 \\
> x_1 = x_2 = 1,\;\;n\in \mathbb N
> $$

I'm trying to understand why I get different results for different guesses of a solution for particular part of the recurrence relation.

I've started by splitting the solution into two parts: homogenous and particular ones. It's known that $$x_n = x_n^{(h)} + x_n^{(p)}$$

Having the above in mind lets solve for homogenous. I've done this with the help of characteristic polynomial:

$$
\lambda^2 - \lambda - 2 = (\lambda + 1)(\lambda - 2) = 0
$$

By this we obtain the form of the homogenous solution:

$$
x_n^{(h)} = C_1\cdot(-1)^n + C_2 \cdot2^n
$$

Here is where things get vague for me. Let's try to guess the form of the non-homogenous solution. I've started with $B\cdot n$, then

$$
B\cdot(n+2) = B\cdot(n+1) + 2Bn + 2 \\
B = \frac{2}{1-2n}
$$

Therefore:

$$
x_n = C_1 \cdot (-1)^n + C_2\cdot2^n + \frac{2}{1-2n}
$$

Using the initial conditions one may find $C_1 = -{13 \over 9}$ and $C_2 = {7\over 9}$. Obtain the final form:

$$
x_n = -{13 \over 9} \cdot (-1)^n + {7 \over 9} \cdot 2^n + \frac{2}{1-2n}
$$

And that result doesn't match the answer in the book. However if I assume that the solution for non-homogenous part is in the form $B$, then $C_1 = -{2\over 3}$ and $C_2 = {2 \over 3}$, which by the steps above results in:

$$
x_n = {1\over 3} \cdot (2^{n+1} - 2\cdot(-1)^n) - 1
$$

being a match with the answer from the book.

I'm trying to understand where it got wrong and why the answers are different. I could have assumed non-homogenous solution to be in various forms which I believe would still lead to some form of solution. Have I made a mistake in my first assumption?

Comment: The solution is always unique because the sequence is uniquely determined by the first two valued that are assumed to be $1$. You are lucky, though, that the method you've used lead to a solution (it might've lead to nothing).

Comment: Your first trial: how do you know that there is no constant terms in the non-homogeneous solution? Would it be general to assume that is $Bn+K$?

Comment: Also when you assuming that the solution is $Bn$, we actually agree by default that $B$ is irrelevant to $n$ as a constant, so the conclusion to your 1st trial should be "the form does not fit".

Comment: You should have tried the same technique you/we applied here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922952/finding-a-closed-form-x-n-for-the-recurrence-relation-x-n2-px-n1-qx/

Comment: @rtybase, Using the linked question I've just arrived at the desired result

Comment: @roman I can recommend [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Count-Introduction-Combinatorics-Applications/dp/3319355082/) ... hopefully you can get one at a good price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's try to guess the form of the non-homogenous solution. I've started with $B\cdot n$

Where of course $\,B\,$ would be a constant for the particular solution to be linear.

> then $\quad\ldots\quad B = \dfrac{2}{1-2n}$

But this $\,B\,$ depends on $\,n\,$ i.e. is *not* a constant. This proves that no linear solutions $\,x_n=B\cdot n\,$ exist.

> However if I assume that the solution for non-homogenous part is in the form $B$

Then $\,B\,$ calculates to $\,-1\,$ i.e. does not depend on $\,n\,$. This proves that a constant solution $\,x_n=-1\,$ does in fact exist, then calculating the respective $\,C_1,C_2\,$ from the initial conditions provides the final, correct answer.

Comment: This actually explains a lot

Comment: @roman Alternatively, if you started with the general form of a linear solution $\,x_n=B_1 \cdot n + B_2\,$, instead, then you would have found $\,B_1=0\,$, $\,B_2=-1\,$. But in this case the constant solution is the first one to try.

Answer (score 2):

If you put $x_n = y_n+c$ so that $y_n$ is a solution to homogenus equation we get $c=-1$.

Since $y_1=y_2= 2$ and $$y_n = a(-1)^n+b2^n$$ we get $$y_n = {2\over 3}(2^n-(-1)^n)$$

or $$x_n = {2\over 3}(2^n-(-1)^n)-1$$

Comment: With this form of $x_{n}$ it is easily seen that $x_{n} = 2 \, J_{n} -1$, where $J_{n}$ are the Jacobsthal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Go up one level:
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} &= x_{n+1}+2x_n +2 \\
x_{n+3} &= x_{n+2}+2x_{n+1}+2
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
x_{n+3}-x_{n+2}=x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}-2x_n
$$
and the characteristic polynomial is
$$
t^3-2t^2-t+2=(t^2-1)(t-2)=(t-1)(t+1)(t-2)
$$
with the added condition that $x_3=5$. Note that you *always* get the original roots among the roots for the new recurrence.

Thus
$$
x_n=\alpha+\beta(-1)^n+\gamma\,2^n
$$
The linear system becomes
\begin{cases}
\alpha-\beta+2\gamma=1 \\[4px]
\alpha+\beta+4\gamma=1 \\[4px]
\alpha-\beta+8\gamma=5
\end{cases}
and, easily, $\alpha=-1$, $\beta=-2/3$, $\gamma=2/3$.

Thus
$$
x_n=-1-\frac{2}{3}(-1)^n+\frac{2}{3}\,2^n
$$

Comment: I got other results for the coefficients, $\alpha = -1$, $\beta = -{2\over 3}$ and $\gamma = {2 \over 3}$

Comment: @roman You're right, I mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

An extended note:

The Jacobstahl numbers satisfy the difference equation
$$J_{n+2} = J_{n+1} + 2 \, J_{n} \, \hspace{5mm} J_{n} \in \{0,1,1,3,5,11,21,43, \cdots \}_{n \geq 0}.$$
By comparison of the difference equations one may see a shifted form of the Jacobsthal equation by seeking $\phi_{n} = \alpha \, J_{n} + \beta$ for which $\phi_{n}$ satisfies
$$\phi_{n+2} = \phi_{n+1} + 2 \, \phi_{n} - 2 \beta.$$
By comparison $\beta = -1$ and $\phi_{n} = \alpha \, J_{n} -1$. Now $\phi_{1} = 1 = \alpha \, 1 - 1$ and leads to $\alpha =2$. From this it is now determined that
$$\phi_{n+2} = \phi_{n+1} + 2 \, \phi_{n} + 2  \, \hspace{5mm} \, \phi_{n} \in \{1,1,5,9, \cdots \}_{n \geq 1}$$
is satisfied by $\phi_{n} = 2 \, J_{n} - 1$.