# How can one convert the number sequence with $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = 2a_{n - 1} + 3a_{n - 2}$ for $n\ge 2$ into its explicit form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How can one convert the number sequence with $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = 2a_{n - 1} + 3a_{n - 2}$ for $n\ge 2$ into its explicit form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you apply the standard methods?

Comment: I would suggest you do the first few instances ($n=2,3,4,5,...$), you should notice a pattern, which can be proved by induction.

Comment: Try to search on MSE for "generating functions" or "characteristic polynomial". There are [plenty of examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922952/finding-a-closed-form-x-n-for-the-recurrence-relation-x-n2-px-n1-qx/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Method of [characteristic polynomials](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/) in order to solve this linear recurrence relation. Take $a_n=k\cdot r^n$. Then, the given recurrence relation implies $$k\cdot r^n=2\cdot k\cdot r^{n-1}+3\cdot k\cdot r^{n-2}\iff r^2=2r+3\iff (r+1)(r-3)=0$$ Therefore $$a_n=k_1\cdot (-1)^n+k_2\cdot 3^n$$ Let $n=0$ and $n=1$ in order to obtain $$a_n=\frac14\cdot \left((-1)^n+3^{n+1}\right)$$ Use induction to prove the result.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks! But why is it 3^(n+1) instead of 3^n as it is k2 * 3^n ?

Comment: It’s actually $3\cdot 3^n=3^{n+1}$